# I follow with error in the part of TO_INTEGER, anyone have any ideas to replace

Tags: vhdl

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_arith.ALL;

ENTITY mult4 IS
    PORT (
        a, b : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
        cout : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END mult4;

ARCHITECTURE behave OF mult4 IS
    SIGNAL result : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    arith_process : PROCESS (a, b)
        VARIABLE p : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 255;
    
    BEGIN
        p := TO_INTEGER(TO_unsigned ('0' & a)) * TO_INTEGER(TO_unsigned ('0' & b));
        result <= TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(p, 8);
    END PROCESS arith_process;
    cout <= result;
END behave;
```

I'm still trying to fix the part of the to_integer, it's giving these errors now:
Error (10327): VHDL error at mult4.vhd(21): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 0 possible definitions
Error (10346): VHDL error at mult4.vhd(21): formal port or parameter "SIZE" must have actual or default value
Error (10784): HDL error at numeric_std_vhdl1993.vhd(712): see declaration for object "SIZE"

does anyone have any idea how to replace this part with something simpler?

Comment: You have included both `numeric_std` and `std_logic_arith`. These both declare `signed` and unsigned types, making neither visible.  Delete nonstandard `std_logic_arith` from your code.  You will also need to replace `to_stdlogicvector` function as this does not exist in `numeric_std `. Instead use `result <= std_logic_vector( to_unsigned( particularly, 8));`

Comment: *does anyone have any idea how to replace this part with something simpler?* With IEEE package numeric_std: `cout  <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));`